# Raspberry Pi3 - Configure 4 DC motors

Tags: transistors, pwm, dc-motor, raspberry-pi, gpio

I need to feed 4 DC motors of 5V on my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B using PWM (Pulse Width Modulation).

Currently, I have the next components: 2 NPM transistors, 1 L293D integrated circuit, diodes, resistors (220 Ohms), wires, etc.

My question is, what is the correct way to feed the 4 motors with 4 GPIO pins?

I will appreciate any kind of help.

[image: circuit diagram]

Comment: You should be using a motor-controller shield, the 5V supply on the Pi won't be able to run motors. Please add a diagram of how you are controlling the motors, do you mean NPN transistors?

Comment: I have attached a circuit diagram on description

Comment: I feed DC motor with GPIO 5V pin, and I have used a resistor of 220 ohms instead of 10K, and that is working fine, nevertheless I want to be sure and know how to connect 4 motors @Ron Beyer